# Nodejs SOAP pfx

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I am trying to use this project https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap to consume a SOAP server and I have pfx file to authenticate, but when I do this:

var soap = require('soap');
var fs = require('fs');

```
var url = 'https://service.com/method.asmx?WSDL';
soap.createClient(url, {wsdl_options: {rejectUnauthorized: false, pfx:     fs.readFileSync('C:/file.pfx'), strictSSL: false, passphrase: 'passwor'} },
  function(err, client) {
    var args = { name: 'stack' };
    client.test(args, function (err, result, body) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
      console.log(body);
  });
});
```

The client was created, found my method but when I call I receive an 403, what can I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions of this tutorial to get the key: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/118339-technote-wsa-00.html

And after set the credentials like sad the readme: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientsslsecurity